# Get distance between one date and another in SQL (ISO format)

Tags: sql, datetime

Let's say I have a table with two columns, where a user places a booking.

```
datefrom               dateto
-------------------------------------------
2009-05-23 00:00:00    2009-05-27 00:00:00
```

How would I use SQL to return how many days the user will be booking for? All I want is to return the number of days.

Comment: What version of SQL?  And why Community Wiki?

Comment: T-SQL, and I didn't mean to make it a Community Wiki. I must have pressed it by accident.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT days = datediff(dd,datefrom,dateto)
FROM table
```

Answer (score 2):

In Oracle:

```
select dateto - datefrom from table;
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL-92:

```
SELECT (dateto - datefrom) DAY
  FROM MyTable;
```